# Approximating an integral with series

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+x}, f$ defined on $[0; 1]$

$ S_n= \sum_{k=0}^n f(\frac{k}{5})$

Why is

$$\frac{f(\frac{k}{5})}{5} \le \int_{\frac{k}{5}}^{\frac{k+1}{5}} f(x)dx\le \frac{f(\frac{k+1}{5})}{5}$$

Comment: Check that $f$ is an increasing function.

Comment: Ok I checked it is then?

Comment: Then use the rectangle method.

Comment: What should I do exactly ?

Comment: For $x\in [\frac{k}{5}; \frac{k+1}{5}]$, $f(\frac {k}{5})\leq f(x) \leq f(\frac {k}{5})$ since $f$ is an increasing function. So : $$\frac{f(\frac{k}{5})}{5}= \int _{k/5}^{(k+1)/5} f(\frac {k}{5})dx\leq \int _{k/5}^{(k+1)/5}f(x)dx \leq \int _{k/5}^{(k+1)/5}f(\frac {k}{5})dx =\frac{f(\frac{k+1}{5})}{5} .$$

Comment: @Patissot: Would you mind converting your comment into an answer? That way the OP can accept your answer and the question disappears from the "unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check that $f'(x)=\frac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}\geq0$ if $x\in [0,1]$.

For $x\in [\frac{k}{5}; \frac{k+1}{5}]$, $f(\frac {k}{5})\leq f(x) \leq f(\frac {k}{5})$ since $f$ is an increasing function. So : $$\frac{f(\frac{k}{5})}{5}= \int _{k/5}^{(k+1)/5} f(\frac {k}{5})dx\leq \int _{k/5}^{(k+1)/5}f(x)dx \leq \int _{k/5}^{(k+1)/5}f(\frac {k}{5})dx =\frac{f(\frac{k+1}{5})}{5} .$$